# Is it possible for an Othello / Reversi game to end without the board being filled?

Tags: othello

Is there any case where an Othello (reversi) game would need to no more moves allowed?
This happen to one of the two players leading to the other to play again is a common thing. Has it ever happened simultaneously to both in the history of the game while leaving positions blank? I mean one cannot move, the other cannot move but there is still room on the board.

**EDIT**
I understand that when no moves are available the game is scored. What I am asking (as it has never occurred to me in the last 3-4 years I am playing the game is

Is there a possibility in which while the board is not yet full no more moves are available by neither of the two players?

How is this possible? Any examples of boards in which this is possible?

Comment: In reversi when this happens the game is not a stalemate.  It is instead scored and the player with the most peaces wins.  I am not sure if this is understood.  Would you want a situation where the board is full AND has an equal number of stones?

Comment: @Andrey edited my question so I could be more specific

Comment: You are still not making if clear if you need the game to end in a tie for the condition to be met

Comment: @Andrey It does not matter how the game ends, tie or not. What I am asking is if cases exist in which the board is not completely full, both players still have pieces (the board is not completely white or black) and no move is possible by neither of the players. Thus ending the game abruptly

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes, it is possible for neither player to be able to make a move without the board being full. The Wikipedia article for [Reversi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reversi) has this example from a competition:

[image]

There are also simpler examples where all the pieces are turned to the same colour ([YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6ehiWOSp_wk)).

Comment: I was asking for cases where it was not the same colour only. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

This is very simple. If one corner is empty, but black has both edges and the diagonal, then black can't go in the corner, and neither can white.

Answer (score 3):

"wipeout" is an example of such an ending, too! It's not something that happens to serious players, but it certainly happens to casual players.

Comment: in my question I specifically state in cases where both have pieces left

Comment: @JohnDemetriou I don't see anywhere in your question that you say you are asking for cases where both sides have pieces left.

Answer (score 3):

[image]

Othello‘s rule book states in the final sentence “it is possible for a game to end before all 64 squares are fillled”.  We just encountered such an edge case. White had the final move, and could not play. Game was called. Black won the game with 34 disks. White has 29.

Answer (score 1):

[image: othello stalemate draw]

This game ends with a draw, neither player able to play.

Comment: This does not appear to add anything new to the question

Comment: Although a valid answer, it was already answered and accepted. Maybe added as an edit to the accepted one?

Comment: This position is not reachable from the standard opening position: One of the four central squares is empty.

Answer (score 0):

[image]
This should more than answer you question i destroyed my friend 29-0 with picture to proof

Comment: Well I would like to see the last step before this :)

Comment: The asker clarified that he was only asking about situations where both players have pieces on the board; this comes across as more showing off a good game you had than an answer to the question.

Comment: @GendoIkari While the OP mentioned in *comments* that they wanted a situation where both players have pieces on the board, they did not say so in the *question*. Comments are *not* the place to put clarifications of your question. If the OP wants examples with both colors, they should edit the question. As it stands, this is an answer to the question as asked.